# Sum of Odd Integers in Python

Tags: python

I need to figure out how to write a for loop in Python that returns NOT print the sum of odd integers given an input. I can't use the sum function or make a list. So far all I have is this:

```
def sumofoddints (n):

    n >= 1

    total = 0

    for num in range (1, n):

        if num % 2 == 1:

            total += n

    return total
```

This doesn't give me the correct sums so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `n` defines the upper bound of range of values that are being considered. adding it to `total` will therefore, not work. add `num` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Should be `total += num`, you're just adding the wrong variable.

Comment: although it is a fix, it is a bad bad one. This will work in O(n), using  math it can be calculated in O(1)

Comment: This is most certainly the answer the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler way using math.

**EDIT:**
 sorry my bad. Here is the corrected formula

```
def sumOdd(n):
    return ((n+1)/2)**2
```

n=1 => 1 = 1

n=3 => 1+3 = 2**2=4

n=5 => 1+3+5 = 3**2=9

n=7 => 1+3+5+7 = 4**2=16

Comment: It should be (n+1)**2/4 if n is odd or n**2/4 if n is even.

Comment: Given that the OP probably attempts to solve the problem (and doing so without using the `sum` function or lists), it kind of defeats the purpose to use plain math here instead of exercising Python.

Comment: I would fire every programmer that would tell me this

Answer (score 0):

Python makes this super easy

```
def sumOdd(n):
  if n%2 == 0:
     n -= 1
  return sum(range(1,n,2))+n
```

The range(1,n,2) starts at 1 and counts by twos until it reaches n
(Range excludes the last digit, for example range(0,2) is 0,1 not 0,1,2
so we add n at the end)

The sum(list) function returns the sum of all the items in a list.

EDIT: It doesn't appear to work for even integers, so I added a -1 if it's even.

Comment: although it is a fix, it is a bad bad one. This will work in O(n), using math it can be calculated in O(1)

Comment: The OP wrote `I can't use the sum function or make a list.`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `total += n` with `total += num` 
because `num` is the one which changes, not `n`.

It has to be like this:

```
def sumofoddints (n):
    n >= 1
    total = 0
    for num in range (1, n):
        if num % 2 == 1:
            total += num

    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply n**2.

Read here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-formula-for-the-sum-of-n-odd-numbers

```
def sumofoddints (n):
  return n**2
```