# without Loops to Sum Range of odd numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

is there any way to sum odd numbers from 1 to n but without any loops and if there isn't a way how can i create this by fast algorithm to do this task in less than n loops.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/37126522/3365922

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the summation in an Arithmetic Series to sum the first `n` odd numbers (not the odd numbers from `0` to `n`)

```
a = 1 # from 1
n = 9999 # to n
d = 2 # and skip every even number
n = int((n - a) / d + 1) # locate the number of term for n
sum = int((n / 2) * (2 * a + (n - 1) * d))
```

Time complexity: O(1), no loop

reference: [Summing an Arithmetic Series](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html)

edit: to fit case for even `n`, e.g. `10000`

```
if n % 2 == 0:
    n = n - 1 # to eliminate the case 10000 and find range 1-9999
```

Comment: This should be the right answer! I was so onto programing mind i forgot what mathematics is ... ‍♂️

Comment: Note that if `n = 2k+1`, the result is `(k+1)^2` (+1)

Comment: I think the question is to find the sum of odds between `1` and `n`, so `n` can be even. I would suggest editing the answer considering that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
sum(range(1, n+1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the one below, which loop through from 1 to n, stepping 2

`sum(range(1,n,2))`